Migrating SAML Extension 1.0.10.RELEASE to spring-security-saml2-service-provider-5.8.x
I am migrating from "spring-security-saml2-core-1.0.10.RELEASE" to "spring-security-saml2-service-provider-5.8.15". My application is in spring XML configuration. I tried doing sample config based on examples given by spring-security.

I did below configuration in my security.xml.
 <security:http auto-config="true">                                           
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/**" access="authenticated" />
    <security:saml2-login />
    <security:saml2-logout />
</security:http>


 <user-service>
         <user name="user" password="{noop}password" authorities="permitAll" />
     </user-service>

     <relying-party-registrations>
         <relying-party-registration registration-id="okta"
             metadata-location="classpath:credentials/metadata-idp.xml">
             <signing-credential
                 certificate-location="classpath:credentials/rp-certificate.crt"
                 private-key-location="classpath:credentials/rp-private.key" />
         </relying-party-registration>

     </relying-party-registrations>


in OKTA IDP, i gave below data (for now, i am ignoring single logout) and assigned one user for the application
Single Sign On URL = http://localhost:2080/login/saml2/sso/okta
Audience URI = http://localhost:2080/saml2/service-provider-metadata/okta


Now, when i tried accessing my application using "http://localhost:8080/test" , I am getting OKTA page to sign in. I entered my login credentials and then it is redirected to
http://localhost:2080/login/saml2/sso/okta with error as shown below

Message The requested resource [/login/saml2/sso/okta] is not available
Description The origin server did not find a current representation for the target resource or is not willing to disclose that one exists.
  [1]: https://i.sstatic.net/V02dW5Lt.png


can someone from [spring-security] help me on it. I am using "Spring-security-saml2-service-provider-5.8.15.jar". Above is the example from "Spring-security-examples" repository, and it is not working. Please confirm if the given jar will not work ?
